# Processing Very Large Files (6Gig or greater) in Java

Tags: java

I was using the following to load file and process as String:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
.
.
.
.

readFile(String inputFile) throws IOException {
   String content = "";

   content = new 
   String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(inputFile)));

   return content;
}

parseAndOutputToNewFile() {

   String string = readFile(inputFile);

   dostuff(string);
}
```

If my files were larger than a couple of Gig, they I would get an output of memory exception within the readFile() and never got to doStuff(). What is the more appropriate way to process larger files? Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need the entire file in memory at once?

Comment: Stream the file, don't read it all into a single `String` in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of [`Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(inputFile))`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-), you should use [`Files.lines(Paths.get(inputFile))`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-), and process the lines as they are streamed.

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(inputFile))) {
    stream. ... // process streamed lines of text here
}
```

Or the Java 7 `for` loop version:

```
try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(inputFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    for (String line; (line = in.readLine(buf)) != null; ) {
        // process `line` here
    }
}
```

If you need blocks of text, instead of lines of text, you should use a [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), e.g. using [`Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(inputFile))`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-), like this:

```
try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(inputFile))) {
    char[] buf = new char[4096];
    for (int len; (len = in.read(buf)) > 0; ) {
        // process `len` chars from `buf` here
    }
}
```

But, it all depends on what `dostuff()` needs to do, i.e. whether what it does can be done in a streaming fashion. Without knowing more about it, we can't give you definitive solutions.

Comment: Thanks for responses.doStuff(string) was taking the string, parsing against know markup, and essentially splitting it  into 2 sections, and writing one section to one output file and the second section to a second output file. However, if I am passing a stream instead (i.e., doStuff(stream)), then I have to stream the input to some output stream until I encounter the known markup (say "<\certainTag>"), and then close the output stream for that section. Since I had a single String, I was just doing things like myString.substring(indexOf(blah), indexOf(bleh). Not sure how to do same with stream.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have sufficient RAM allocated to the JVM (heap) to read the whole file in a string.

In order to bypass this, you'll need to modify the `doStuff` method to use a `Reader` and process the input lazily.

```
try(Reader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile)){
    doStuff(reader);
}
```